# Tradução faltando no novo Boletim da Comunidade

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, internacionalização, boletim-da-comunidade

Ficou legal o novo Boletim da Comunidade na coluna da direita, com os posts em destaque separados dos demais. Porém, os novos cabeçalhos estão saindo em inglês:

[image]

Comment: Dá pra resolver antes do jogo? :D

Comment: Dá, o Marc Gravell já não tem mais para quem torcer :D

Comment: Eu não posso. Tem que ver com alguém do dev team....

Comment: @Gabe , bfavaretto. Apenas os tópicos que tem a tag `debate` são linkadas ali? Num teste rápido cliquei nos 5 atuais para mim e todos eles tem a tag "debate", é proposital? Se foi apenas coincidência diria que `Debates mais ativos` não seria a tradução mais apropriada, talvez "tópicos" no lugar de "debates" acho que ficaria melhor.

Comment: @Math Acho que são só debates mesmo, considerados *hot* pelo algoritmo de *hotness* da SE.

Comment: Achei que era tudo do Meta. Ok, obrigado pela explicação.

Comment: @Math http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130621/how-are-the-contents-of-the-community-bulletin-determined

Comment: Quando aparece aquela caixa azul, logo abaixo do boletim, aparece a mensagem: "Love this site?", sem contar que tem alguns bugs, o botão fica cortado, pois é maior que a caixa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With some assistance from Gabe this is now sorted.

The translation pipeline was not working fully, so he was not able to make the changes directly.

Sorry for the trouble!